# Formatting data based on string or number - google visualization

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, google-visualization, spreadsheet

I have database in PHPMyAdmin, Excel and CSV format (all the same just different formats). To put this data in a table in google visualization numbers are written as they are but string values need to have a ' either side of the text. For example:

```
['MESSI','FC BARCELONA','ARGENTINA',169,67,25,'Left foot','SS',98,99,38,74,9855704866],
```

My database has over 2000 rows so manually doing this isn't an option. Is there a way in any of these formats to make all string variables have the ' either side and all numbers to be written by themselves. The CSV format already splits cells using a comma which I need but it would also be useful if each row started with [ and ended with ] . Anyone know how to do this using any of these formats?

Comment: If you were to pull the data from MySQL, would you be using PHP to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Excel can also automatically quote string values when you save a spreadsheet as csv. Do look through the options

Alternatively, you can write a simple formula to achieve your end result

Let us say your spreadhseet has a row like this

```
        A             B          C          D     E
 1    MESSI    FC BARCELONA  ARGENTINA     169   69
```

In  column F, you can create a formula like this (It can be in another sheet also)

```
 ="['" & A1 & "','" & B1 & "','" & C1 & "'," & D1 & "," & E1 & "']"
```

You can then paste this formula in all your rows. Now column F will have your desired output.

**Update:**

Since you also have this data in an sql database, you can also write a simple select query like this (I am assuming the table structure)

```
SELECT "['", 
       StringField1, 
       "',", 
       NumericField2, 
       ",'", 
       StringField2,
       "']"
FROM table1
WHERE <Condition>
```

Notice carefully. We are including an hard coded string fields (in double quotes) at places where we need those special strings to appear in the result set.

Comment: Any idea where these options are? Would they give you the option open and close a row with [ ] too?

Comment: Have a look: http://www.lenashore.com/2012/general/how-to-add-quotes-to-your-cells-in-excel-automatically/

Comment: To answer your second part of the question, No - it does not add [] around the row. You can however use the method I described above to add it yourself